# MD5 sum in TCP connection

Tags: c, linux, tcp, md5

I am trying to use function like `MD5_Init`,`MD5_Update` etc.

I try to `getline` from my file in server and send, in client I `read` 100 chars.

Here is my most important part of code:
server.c

```c
connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr*) NULL,NULL);

if(sposob == 1)     
{
    while( (read = getline(&line,&len,stream) ) != -1)
    {

        write(connfd,line,read); // raad = zwraca wartosc ile   
        sleep(czas);    // mala precyzja
        line[read-1] = '\0';        

        if( !odbierz_i_policz_md5(connfd,line,read) )
        {
            perror("Blad MD5 \n");
        }

    }
}

// my function
char *str2md5(const char *str, int length) {
    int n;
    MD5_CTX c;
    unsigned char digest[16];
    char *out = (char*)malloc(33);

    MD5_Init(&c);

    while (length > 0) {
        if (length > 512) {
            MD5_Update(&c, str, 512);
        } else {
            MD5_Update(&c, str, length);
        }
        length -= 512;
        str += 512;
    }

    MD5_Final(digest, &c);

    for (n = 0; n < 16; ++n) {
        snprintf(&(out[n*2]), 16*2, "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[n]);
    }

    return out;
}
int odbierz_i_policz_md5(int gniazdo,char *str1, int length)
{
    char *out = (char*)malloc(33);
    char *wiad;

    if(recv(gniazdo, out, 33,0) != -1)
    {
        wiad = str2md5(str1,length) ;
        if (strncmp (wiad,out,33) == 0)
        {
            free(out);
            free(wiad);
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            free(out);
            free(wiad);     
            return 0;
        }   
    }
    else{
        fprintf(stdout,"Recv error! \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }

}
```

client.c

```c
#define BUFLEN 100 
while( (n = read(sockfd,recvBuff,sizeof(recvBuff-1))) > 0 )
{
    char *wiad; 
    recvBuff[n] = 0;        
    write(fd,recvBuff,n);
    /*  if(fprintf(stdout,"%s",recvBuff) == EOF)
    {
        perror("fprintf");
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    */  

    // odebral - teraz wyslac
    wiad = str2md5(recvBuff,n);
    fprintf(stdout,"Wiadomosc %s \n",recvBuff);
    if( send(sockfd,wiad,33,0) == -1 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failure Sending Message\n");
    }
    free(wiad);
}
```

My problem:
I have diffrent MD5 in client and server ! I thing that MD5 should have in both site(client,server) the same message. Where is my mistake? How to improve my code?

Comment: I think you are overwriting the last byte of the string with `\0` in the server. The string is already null-terminated so you don't have to do it.

Comment: You shouldn't use MD5 if you just want to make sure the data is ok. Use something like CRC32. If you need the cryptographic properties of MD5, use something that has not been broken yet such as SHA3.

Comment: I have to use MD5 like that. I delete on server site \0 and my output to compere >md5: d3e25f16b3f59fecccda12d29b3a6736 
>sum3: 3a7dc0c282082d9f7339864b4d504b45 so still not work :(

Comment: There obviously must be a difference in the buffers after transmission. Print the buffers (exactly as they are passed to the str2md5 function) for debugging and compare them carefully.

Comment: Yes - it is diffrent string, but I don't know how to correctly repair the tcp send and recv so as to have the same data.

Comment: What is the difference between the strings? I don't mean the MD5 strings, I mean the actual strings that you run MD5 against.

Comment: I just send line of text like "Here is my text bla bla" and in other side I read like "Here" "is my text", "bla bla". For "Here"  I count MD5 and I suppose - it is my mistake. I reall don't know how to repeit it, I want to count MD5 for the same text in both sides.

Comment: try only running MD5 whenever you have a line terminated by \n

Comment: Yes - it will be the best solution but Could you give me example how to do it in my code - using answer the question? Where insert cheching the \n I think that 100 charakters is enough to read one line, Am I wrong?